# How can I optimize this query? I've to use two INNER JOIN for the same table (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way where I can avoid to do two INNER JOIN for the same table in this case?

```
    SELECT  B.CostCatCd As CostCatCd,
            F.CountryDesc AS SenderCountry,
            B.SenderCompanycd AS SenderCompanyCd,
            D.CountryDesc As ReceivingCountry,
            B.BillCompanycd AS ReceivingCompanyCd,  
            SUM(B.BillAmt) as Amount

    FROM    Bill B      
    INNER JOIN  Company C
    ON          B.FY = C.FY
    AND         B.CycleCd = C.CycleCd
    AND         B.BillCompanyCd = C.CompanyCd
    INNER JOIN  Country D
    ON          B.FY = D.FY
    AND         B.CycleCd = D.CycleCd
    AND         C.CountryCd = D.CountryCd
    INNER JOIN  Company E
    ON          B.FY = E.FY
    AND         B.CycleCd = E.CycleCd
    AND         B.SenderCompanyCd = E.CompanyCd
    INNER JOIN  Country F
    ON          B.FY = F.FY
    AND         B.CycleCd = F.CycleCd
    AND         E.CountryCd = F.CountryCd
```

I'm trying to improve the performance in a SP and maybe this is something that may be updated. I've the same concern for both tables (Company & Country).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your query is missing a group by.

Comment: Have you tried doing the query without the company table? Since there are join conditions from B to D and B to F, is it necessary to look at tables C and E for the query that aren't returning columns from those tables?

Comment: @JBKing how do you intend to select the country information without the company?

Comment: Try this for the joins:

    INNER JOIN  Country D
    ON          B.FY = D.FY
    AND         B.CycleCd = D.CycleCd
    INNER JOIN  Country F
    ON          B.FY = F.FY
    AND         B.CycleCd = F.CycleCd

Comment: Your query does not look bad except for all of the fields you have to join on to relate the tables together. It is interesting you do not have a single unique key to relate Country to Company, like Country.CountryID -> Company.CountryID. Are you sure you need all those fields to join? You could add multiple column indexes to the tables. Company (CompanyCD, CycleCD, FY), Country (CountryCD, CycleCD, FY).

Comment: "Is there any way where I can avoid to do two INNER JOIN for the same table in this case?" Not without changing your schema in ways that would probably not be an improvement.

Comment: @A ツ I've removed the group part because I thought it would not be relevant. @JBKing I've tried with this JOIN and it is not working for me. I am trying to avoid use the company table in the join.

Comment: In my opinion you can remove second and forth joins without any problem, and take values for tables D and F from C and E accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Without the details, it's not so simple to give suggestions, but you should look into actual query plan and statistics IO output. Those give quite good idea what's going on with your SQL.

If the query is running slow, you should check the following things:

- The table with biggest logical reads
- Scans in query plan
- Key lookups in query plan when it happens for a large number of rows
- Spools, Sorts, Spills into temp db

For indexing it looks like a good candidate for indexes would be:

Company: CompanyCd, CycleCd, FY (+ CountryCd as included column)

Country: CountryCd, CycleCd, FY (+ CountryDesc as included column)

Everything of course depends on how often the rows are being updated, since indexes will slow those (slightly), but guessing that companies or countries don't get many updates. I made a guess about selectivity of the columns and that's why the columns in the index are in that order.

Indexing Bill properly is a good idea too, but since where clause is missing it's not possible to give any suggestions.

Comment: For the Company table:

There are:
- 3 PK (FY, CycleCd and CompanyCd)
- 1 Clustered Index with FY, CycleCd and CompanyCd.
- 1 Non-Clustered Index with FY, CycleCd, CompanyCd, CountryCd.

For Country table:
- 3 PK (FY, CycleCd and CountryCd)
- 1 Clustered Index with FY, CycleCd and CountryCd

Comment: If your clustered indexes already have FY, CycleCD and CompanyCD / CountryCD the other indexes aren't most likely helping, but changing the order of the columns in the index could help, assuming CompanyCD / CountryCD are the ones that limit the rows best